# Apache2: Redirect all requests to www subdomain of requested domain

Tags: apache, redirect

I'm trying to set up a server that will redirect incoming domain requests to the www. subdomain of the requested domain.

I've been looking for a couple of hours but can't find anything close to what I need.  Most redirects to www. seem to require the name of the domain that you are redirecting, whereas I would like to redirect based upon the requested domain.

[rewrite rule for root](http://eldapo.lembobrothers.com/2011/01/31/apache-rewrite-rule-for-root-domain/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I worked out the answer to my own question.

Editing the sites-available/default configuration file (Ubuntu Server) I modified it so that it looked like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```